# How to get element which has particular following-sibling element?

Tags: html, xpath

I want to select P element which has 'ul' as immediate following-sibling from below sample xml.

```
<root>
<p>abc</p>
<br>
<p>def</p>
<br>
<p>FEATURES</p> 
<ul> 
    <li>design</li> 
    <li>softness</li>        
</ul> 
<p>SIZING</p> 
<ul>
    <li>17'' x 24''</li> 
    <li>20'' x 32''</li> 
    <li>24'' x 38''</li> 
</ul> 
<p>CONSTRUCTION &amp; CARE</p> 
<ul>
    <li>Nylon</li> 
    <li>Latex backing</li> 
    <li>Machine wash</li> 
    <li>Made in the USA</li>
</ul>
<p>SUSTAINABILITY FEATURES</p>
</root>
```

I have tried this `//root/p[following-sibling::ul]` xpath but didn't get desired answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one to get output:

```
//p[following-sibling::*[position()=1 and self::ul]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"//root/ul/preceding-sibling::p[1]"
```

I don't think this needs an explanation :), it's already understandable.